# Is there a way to `fromIntegral . fromEnum` that works with all Integers?

Tags: haskell

```
> (fromIntegral . fromEnum) True
1
```

Good.

```
> (fromIntegral . fromEnum) (10000 :: Int)
10000
```

Good.

```
λ (fromIntegral . fromEnum) 100000000000000000000
7766279631452241920
```

Not good.

I'm doing some bit banging with `Data.Bits` and looking for a general way to combine fields represented by `Bool`, `Int` and `Integer`. `Integer` fields may be very large.

### Update

The overall thing I'm trying to do looks like this:

```
fromExchange :: Exchange -> Integer
fromExchange e = foldr combineBits 0 collectBits
  where
    combineBits = ((.|.) . ($ e))
    collectBits =
      [ (`shiftL` 127) . toBits . doCommand
      , (`shiftL` 126) . toBits . readComplete
      , (`shiftL` 116) . fromIntegral . destId
      , (`shiftL` 64) . address
      , payload
      , (`shiftL` 108) . fromIntegral . mask
      , (`shiftL` 104) . fromIntegral . fromCommand . command
      ]

toBits :: Enum a =>
          a -> Integer
toBits = fromIntegral . fromEnum
```

I'd like to factor out `toBits/fromIntegral` if possible.

Comment: well `fromEnum` goes to `Int` so you will always hit it's bounds somewhere. - But what do you really want to do here - from the last two examples it looks like want it just to be `id` on numbers?

Comment: `Bool`, `Int`, and `Integer` is a small set of types, how about just make your own class?